# How to read aaf file using pyaaf traversing till the edge to retrieve values?

Tags: python

I am given a task at workplace to read aaf file to fetch data and read its values to be passed to a different software.

How can I retrieve all key value pair in order deep down the aaf tree?

While experimenting I have noticed all  mobs do not have mob_id ! Like this many attributes are sometimes there and sometimes missing in the element/components.

Comment: pyaaf looks up to the task https://pyaaf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I have been reading docs already

Comment: You should be able to iterate over aaf objects like a typical dictionary e.g 
for k,v in main_composition.items():
    print (k,v)

Comment: ‘compositionMob’ object has no attribute ‘items’

Comment: items() is a dictionary method in Python. Since the objects are dictionaries I'd imagine you could iterate through them like any dictionary.

Comment: @Sflagg by the method you suggested I traversed to segments > components > data definitions but couldn’t locate the source clip which is what I am after !